# not understanding which one is the class and which one is the method in the below statement

Tags: apex

```
Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
```

In `Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results`, if I understand correctly

1. `Messaging.SendEmailResult` is the class
2. `results` is the list of `Messaging.SendEmailResult[]` class

Am I correct?

Comment: You almost have it. `results` is a list of `Messaging.SendEmailResult`, the `[]` indicates that it's an array. Go through [Build Apex coding skills](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-apex-coding-skills) trail, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty much correct.

`Messaging` is the "namespace"
`SendEmailResult` is a class within that namespace

`Messaging.SendEmailResult[]` is just one way of declaring a list of that class, and is functionaly equivalent to `List<Messaging.SendEmailResult>`

Comment: Really appreciate.Actually i am trying to learn Apex on my own, i came across this piece of code, not able to understand a particular line
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
email.setToAddresses(new String[] { 'admin@acme.com' });
email.setSubject('my subject');
email.setPlainTextBody('plain text body');
List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { email }); can you please explain what this line means.   List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.Email[] { email });

Comment: @user18187 Comments aren't a good place for code, and it sounds like that's a different question. If you're new to Apex (or any aspect of Salesforce, really), then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is probably a better initial resource than this site is. You'd also do well to familiarize yourself with [the official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm)